# How to deduce the formula for arrangement in groups?

Tags: combinatorics

> The number of ways in which $n$ different things can be arranged into $r$ different groups is $$n! \cdot \dbinom{n - 1}{r - 1} $$.

This is the quote from my book. However, it didn't offer any explanation. Now, how is it deduced?

Comment: Note that one needs to make a peculiar interpretation of the wording to get the formula. For example, there are $3$ ways to divide the people $a,b,c$ into $2$ non-empty groups. But the formula gives $12$.

Comment: I think the formula is meant by interpreting $ab|c$ and $ba|c$ as different groups.

Comment: @André Nicolas: You seem to right, sir. I'm really baffled & confused. Even the book went further to give formula for "distribution" which is different from "arrangement" formula here. I'm thinking to post another quo concerning this.

Comment: @Marc: In addition to counting order within groups, one also needs to assume that the groups are **named**, making $ab|c$ is different from $c|ab$.

Comment: @user36790:  If we are thinking of dividing the people into $r$ named groups, we are essentially counting onto functions from an $n$-element set to an $r$-element set. This brings up the Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind (please see Wikipedia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to look at this is to line up your $n$ elements
\begin{equation}
e_1e_2\cdots e_n
\end{equation}
Now we want to divide this particular sequence into $r$ groups. That means that we need to pick $r-1$ spaces between elements to divide. One example of $5$ elements into $3$ groups is
\begin{equation}
e_1e_2|e_3|e_4e_5
\end{equation}
Note that there are $n-1$ possible spaces to choose from. Therefore, for a particular sequence we get $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$ choices for the placement of the divisors. Now, if we count two groups different if the elements in them are placed in a different order, then we just need to multiply by the total number of line ups, which equals $n!$.